# Heroku Application Error while Deploying Django application

Tags: django, heroku

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twZQS.png)

Please help me with this error

Comment: Welcome to SO, please refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to your static files.
Try the following:

- heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
- git push heroku main
- heroku run python manage.py migrate
- heroku run 'bower install --config.interactive=false;grunt
  prep;python
- manage.py collectstatic --noinput'
- heroku config:unset DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC
- heroku run python manage.py collectstatic

Hope this helps.

---

I can also see the console says: `could not find module 'whitenoise'`. Have you set your requirements.txt properly?

Comment: Everything above the line looks like a wild guess. Please focus on what we _know_ when answering questions here. The missing module is much more likely to be relevant as it is referenced in the log output.

Comment: @Chris Although it may look like a wild guess, I have had a very similar problem (maybe even the same?) a little while ago. So what i have written above the line was my solution when i had that problem, hence i gave it as an answer.

Comment: Yet there is evidence of a missing module. _That_ is what your answer should address, and not as an afterthought.